# Why would the 'naive' definition of homomorphism not work?

Tags: universal-algebra

What would be a counterexample to the condition in the definition of a homomorphism that goes like down below?

$h(f^\mathfrak{A}(a_1,...,a_n)) = h(f^\mathfrak{B}(a_1,...,a_n))$

[as opposed to the original condition, $h(f^\mathfrak{A}(a_1,...,a_n)) = f^\mathfrak{B}(h(a_1),...,h(a_n))$]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proposed definition doesn't even "parse" in the first place: $h$ only applies to elements of $\mathfrak{A}$ and $f^\mathfrak{B}$ only applies to (and only outputs) elements of $\mathfrak{B}$, so there's no way to make sense of the right hand side expression "$h(f^\mathfrak{B}(a_1,...,a_n))$."

(OK, technically if $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ have "overlapping domains" (e.g. if $\mathfrak{A}=\mathfrak{B}$) this may *happen to* parse, but it won't make sense in general. And even in this case it won't behave well: for instance, as Troposphere observes every map $\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{A}$ *whatsoever* would constitute a homomorphism according to your definition in the case $\mathfrak{A}=\mathfrak{B}$.)

Comment: In fact _every map whatsoever_ would satisfy the condition when $\mathfrak A=\mathfrak B$.

Comment: @Troposphere Good point, fixed! Not sure how I missed that ...

Comment: What I had in mind was a universe that was a generating set $X$ (or ''overlapping domains'') but yes, that's completely useless anyway. Thanks!